# linear Independence testing by LP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

We have a set of vectors P1,...,Pk. Each vector has n dimension. These vectors are linearly independent if the only solution to the following problem is lambda(i) = 0 for each 0 <= i <= k:

lambda(1)P1 + lambda(2)P2 + ... + lambda(k)Pk = 0;

where lambda(i) is a real number. 
More rigorous formulation is available in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

I am dealing with modeling this problem with an LP for a long while and so far no answer achieved. Would you please help me with this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are dealing with a vector space of dimension `n`. If there are more vectors `P1,...,Pk`, then the input is not linearly independet; so suppose that `k<=n`. The goal is to determine the dimension of the linear hull of the input. Solve `n` linear programs of the form

```
max e_{i}x s. t. Ax = e_{i}
```

for each `i` in `{1,...,n}` where `e_{i}` denotes the `i`-th unit vector. The number of solvable linear programs should yield the dimension of the input's linear hull, which means that these number equals `k` if and only if the input is linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do  that exactly  I described. I need vector lambda.